# Docker: Running container from CLI fails but not from docker desktop, RTENETLINK Oper not permitted

Tags: linux, macos, docker, containers, centos8

I am learning docker, I downloaded it to my Mac and I was able to run my first docker container from the desktop app. Launching the container for the same image from the command line fails.

The error log is below showing RteNetLink failure.

Any thoughts why and how it can be fixed?

```
% docker run ghcr.io/nokia/srlinux
Thu Aug  5 19:36:13 UTC 2021: entrypoint.sh called
Thu Aug  5 19:36:13 UTC 2021: renaming docker interface eth0 to mgmt0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
Cannot find device "mgmt0"
Device "mgmt0" does not exist.
Cannot find device "mgmt0"
Thu Aug  5 19:36:14 UTC 2021: turning off checksum offloading on mgmt0
netlink error: Operation not permitted
Thu Aug  5 19:36:14 UTC 2021: starting sshd
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA DSA ECDSA ED25519 
mount: /var/log/srlinux/buffer: permission denied.
Thu Aug  5 19:36:14 UTC 2021: Calling boot_run script
chmod: cannot access '/dev/console': No such file or directory
chmod: missing operand after '0666'
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
/usr/bin/find: '/var/log/srlinux/file': No such file or directory
logmgr_set_env.sh: plain_bootup_start
Thu Aug  5 19:36:15 UTC 2021  logmgr_set_env.sh: restart of rsyslogd
Failed to set capabilities on file `/usr/sbin/tcpdump' (No such file or directory)
usage: setcap [-q] [-v] [-n <rootid>] (-r|-|<caps>) <filename> [ ... (-r|-|<capsN>) <filenameN> ]

 Note <filename> must be a regular (non-symlink) file.
Thu Aug  5 19:36:15 UTC 2021: entrypoint.sh done, executing /bin/bash
```

And when I ran the container in interactive mode, I checked the OS release, it is CentOS Stream.

```
[user@33681341ddf6 /]$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Stream"
VERSION="8"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="8"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Stream 8"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"
HOME_URL="https://centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="CentOS Stream"
```

Comment: That looks like you're somehow trying to run a virtual-machine image (that's reconfiguring network interfaces, running auxiliary daemons, creating multiple log directories, ...) instead of a light-weight single-process Docker image.  Do you have the image's Dockerfile?  If you're just learning, would a simpler application be better as a first exercise?

Comment: I am not just learning dockers, I am also trying to run the Nokia SR Linux image which has some unique capabilities. I need to test this image and build custom network applications on top. 

You are right though, I should go simpler: 
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launching the container for the same image from the command line doesn't fail, if you look at the logs of the container that you started with Docker Desktop you'll see the same lines.

What happens is that the centos dockerfile use bash as its default command.

When you run a container it will attach to stdout and stderr by default but not stdin.

adding `-i` will attach stdin.

adding `-t` will provide you with a pseudo-tty

To actually use bash you'll need to provide both  : `-it`

To sum up, here's how to mimick what Docker Desktop does, starting the container in the background with `-d`:

```
docker run -it -d ghcr.io/nokia/srlinux
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Without the -it -d the container was shutting down. Now it is in running state.